# how to limit the records to display under <h:selectManyCheckbox>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow, jsf-2.2

I would like to limit the no of record to be displayed under .

Here is the code snippet.

//Filter Class used to display checkboxes

```
class Filter {
 public String filterValueName;
}
```

// Fields declared under BEAN

```
public List<String> filterValuesChecked;
public List<Filter> filterValues;
```

// XHTML to iterate over list

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{fltrResult.filterValuesChecked}" layout="pageDirection" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{fltrResult.filterValues}" var="fltrVal"
        itemLabel="#{fltrVal.filterValueName}"
        itemValue="#{fltrVal.filterValueName}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Above code is working very well, but here issue is List filterValues contains 1000 records, and I want to display only 5-10 checkboxes and after that  Link to visualize whole list.

I had wasted so much time on google to find out the  solution but didn't get it.
Please provide the way how can I achieve the same

Thanks in Advance,
Chirag

Comment: You could create an alternate `List<Filter>` where you store the values to display.

Comment: I just have idea for you. Maybe you should try to put button instead of selectManyCheckBox. That button will show up dialog, put there dataTable so user can pick up those items. Since you will have dataTable you can also implement lazy loading and it wont matter how much records you are searching / clicking / trying to show :)

Comment: Like @LuiggiMendoza - you have to do the shortlist yourself. There's no out-of-the-box attribute that'll shorten the list for you

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza : I am thinking about "rendered", if I can use some logic with <ui:repeat> that may help.

Comment: Rendered wont help you here. It would be better to prepare the subset and use it for your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In the Bean:

```
private final int MAXNUMBER = 10; // e.g.
public List<String> filterValuesChecked;
public List<Filter> filterValues;

// With a fixed limit:
public List<Filter> getRestrictedFilterValues(){
    return this.filterValues.subList(0, MAXNUMBER);
}

// With a dynamic limit:
public List<Filter> getRestrictedFilterValues(int maximum){
    return this.filterValues.subList(0, maximum);
}
```

In the xhtml:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{fltrResult.filterValuesChecked}" layout="pageDirection">
<f:selectItems value="#{fltrResult.getRestrictedFilterValues()}" var="fltrVal"
    itemLabel="#{fltrVal.filterValueName}"
    itemValue="#{fltrVal.filterValueName}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Of cause, you can use any select-algorithm in the `getRestrictedFilterValues`-Method.

Addition: Consider the usage of a (custom) converter in this cases, so you don't have to handle with Strings but can directly get `Filter`-Objects as result (=> `public List<Filter> filterValuesChecked;`). See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm

Comment: nice idea and Yup!!! I'm aware about the custom converter. Thanks... It will work for me.